# firebase serve: Error: listen EACCES: permission denied

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Hi I am new to firebase and I came across an error. I have a file index.js in my functions folder and this file contains only one function helloWorld. When I run this function using firebase serve --only functions command, it gives error.
I am attaching a picture of the error kindly check it. Thanks

And here is the index.js file:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
 });
```

The error it is showing is:

> E:\gc-functions>firebase serve --only functions
>   !  Your requested "node" version "8" doesn't match your global version "10"
>   +  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5000
>   i  functions: Watching "E:\gc-functions\functions" for Cloud Functions...
>   !  Default "firebase-admin" instance created!
>   i  functions: HTTP trigger initialized at http://localhost:5000/learn-firebase-2-5fd83/us-central1/helloWorld
>   i  functions: HTTP trigger initialized at http://localhost:5000/learn-firebase-2-5fd83/us-central1/helloTayyib
>   i  functions: Beginning execution of "helloTayyib"
>   !  Default "firebase-admin" instance created!
>    events.js:174
>          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>          ^
>
> Error: listen EACCES: permission denied C:\Users\Tayyab\AppData\Local\Temp\firebase_emulator_invocation_8960.sock
>        at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1253:19)
>        at listenInCluster (net.js:1318:12)
>        at Server.listen (net.js:1416:5)
>        at Function.listen (C:\Users\Tayyab\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
>        at Promise (C:\Users\Tayyab\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:359:46)
>        at new Promise ()
>        at C:\Users\Tayyab\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:332:15
>        at Generator.next ()
>        at C:\Users\Tayyab\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:7:71
>        at new Promise ()
>    Emitted 'error' event at:
>        at emitErrorNT (net.js:1297:8)
>        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
>        at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:757:11)
>        at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
>        at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show images of text.  Copy the text into the question so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1280